# python processing. why wont background(0,0,0) paint over my shape?

Tags: python, background, processing, vertex

This is my first time asking a question here, so my apologies if I don't get it quite right.

I am trying to make a shape that changes each time draw() iterates. But I am unable to "cover up" the prior frame using background(0,0,0). instead, all prior frames are "piling up" on top of eachother.

```
import processing
import random

def setup():
    processing.size(500,500, processing.P3D)
  

def draw():
  processing.background(255,0,0)
  processing.stroke(255)

  processing.beginShape()
  processing.vertex(50,6)
  processing.vertex(50,17)
  processing.vertex(100,random.randint(20,30))
  processing.endShape()

processing.run()
```

As I understand it, the shape defined by the 3 verticies SHOULD get painted over by the background() function, but that isn't happening.

any advice would be highly appreciated!!♥

Comment: Where were / are you calling `background(0,0,0)`?

Comment: my bad. the above is a code-snippet instead uses processing.background(255,0,0) in the first line of the draw() function.  only difference is it makes the background bright red instead of black

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why background is not working but maybe use a rectangle to cover up the canvas instead

something like this:

```
processing.rect(0,0,500,500)
```